# Function to accept multiple struct types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I'm trying to pass in two different structs (that inherit from the same protocol) into one struct init method but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[TopContentModel]' to '[TopModel]'
```

Here's the code that I have:

```
protocol TopModel {

}

struct TopContentModel: TopModel {
    var type: TableType?
    var contentType: ContentType?
    var title : String?
    var total: Float?
}

struct TopPlatformModel: TopModel {
    var platform: PlatformType?
    var total: Float?
    var type: TableType?
}

struct ChartInfo {
    var title: String?
    var type: ChartType?
    var prefix: String = ""
    var labels: [String]?
    var values: [Float]?
    var list: [TopModel]?
    var formatter: NSNumberFormatter?
    var special: String?
    var secondSpecial: String?
    var color: String?
}

var topEarningData = [TopContentModel]()

ChartInfo(title: "Top Earning Assets", type: .TopContent, prefix: "$", labels: nil, values: nil, list: topEarningData, formatter: nil, special: nil, secondSpecial: nil, color: "#37e0af")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare `topEarningData` as

```
var topEarningData = [TopModel]()
```

so that it meets the specification in `ChartInfo`.  Then add instances of `TopContentModel` or `TopPlatformModel` as needed.

```
 36> var topEarningData = [TopModel]() 
topEarningData: [TopModel] = 0 values
 37> topEarningData.append(TopContentModel())
 38> topEarningData.append(TopPlatformModel()) 
 39> topEarningData
$R1: [TopModel] = 2 values {
  [0] = {
    type = nil
    contentType = nil
    title = nil
    total = nil
  }
  [1] = {
    platform = nil
    total = nil
    type = nil
  }
}
 40> ChartInfo(title: "Top Earning Assets", type: nil, prefix: "$", labels: nil, values: nil, list: topEarningData, formatter: nil, special: nil, secondSpecial: nil, color: "#37e0af") 
$R2: ChartInfo = {
  title = "Top Earning Assets"
  type = nil
  prefix = "$"
  labels = nil
  values = nil
  list = 2 values {
    [0] = {
      type = nil
      contentType = nil
      title = nil
      total = nil
    }
    [1] = {
      platform = nil
      total = nil
      type = nil
    }
  }
  formatter = nil
  special = nil
  secondSpecial = nil
  color = "#37e0af"
}
 41>
```

Comment: This worked thank you!

Comment: You can also downcast your array when you provide it to the function `list: topEarningData as [TopModel]`